Use wrapKey to encrypt one public key with another public key: OperationError
My application calls for encrypting one public key with another public key.  I can generate both keys, but calling wrapKey throws an OperationError with no details regarding why it is failing.
const {publicKey: wrappingKey} = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {name: 'RSA-OAEP', modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]), hash: 'SHA-256'},
  true, ['decrypt', 'wrapKey', 'unwrapKey']);
const {publicKey: myKey} = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {name: 'RSA-OAEP', modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]), hash: 'SHA-256'},
  true, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
try {
  const output = await window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey('jwk', myKey, wrappingKey, {name: 'RSA-OAEP', modulusLength: 2048, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]), hash: 'SHA-256'});
  console.log(output);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}

What about this operation is causing a problem? Running in Chrome.
The empty error looks like this:
{
stack: "OperationError"
code: 0
message: ""
name: "OperationError"
}


It seems that this particular key scheme has a maximum length of data it can encrypt.  By increasing the modulusLength on the wrapping key and reducing the modulusLength on the key being encrypted, I managed to get it to succeed.
const {publicKey: wrappingKey} = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {name: 'RSA-OAEP', modulusLength: 2000, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]), hash: 'SHA-256'},
  true, ['decrypt', 'wrapKey', 'unwrapKey']);
const {publicKey: myKey} = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {name: 'RSA-OAEP', modulusLength: 512, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]), hash: 'SHA-256'},
  true, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
try {
  const output = await window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey('jwk', myKey, wrappingKey,
    {name: 'RSA-OAEP', modulusLength: 512, publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]), hash: 'SHA-256'});
  console.log(output);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}


Note that 512-bit RSA is very unsafe.

(As mentioned in the linked answer, you should communicate a symmetric key using the wrapping key – which I think, with currently available Web Crypto APIs, means generating it separately and encrypting it with RSA-OAEP – and then do the wrapKey with the symmetric key.)

It's a little convoluted to explain in this comment box, but I'm working on a ring of key exchange such that each agent in the handshake ring has no knowledge of which key belongs to which other agent.  The goal is not to open a communication channel, the goal is to allow encryption of a message without knowing who has the key to decrypt it.  As for un-safety. this is for a fun hobby project so resilience to brute-force attack is not in my threat model :)

I uploaded what I have so far, it has an explanation of the idea with a diagram. https://jonah.id/secret-santa
